# What is the alternative of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, http, plugins, server

Am using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in a php script to get a url of page but envato theme check plugin shows a warning.

`WARNING: Found $_SERVER in the file framework/class-easy.php. PHP Global Variable found. Ensure the context is safe and reliable.
Line 253: return ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
global $wp;
echo home_url( $wp->request )
```